# Foreach con Smarty

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, smarty

Estoy intentando hacer un foreach con Smarty, pero me dice que no hay datos

```html
$service = new Service;

$services = $service->getList();

$smarty->assign('services', $services);
return $services;
```

He probado si ese return devuelve algo y sí. devuelve el objeto smarty y dentro de él:

```html
[value] => Array
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [CREATION_DATE] => 2020-02-10 19:50:30
                    [MODIFICATION_DATE] => 2020-02-10 19:50:30
                    [CODE] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [CREATION_DATE] => 2020-02-10 19:50:30
                    [MODIFICATION_DATE] => 2020-02-10 19:50:30
                    [CODE] => 2
                )

        )
```

Y este es mi foreach:

```html
 {$services|@print_r}
            {foreach from=$services item=service}
                <tr>
                    <th>{$service["ID"]}</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
  {/foreach}
```

Y el error que muestra

> Notice: Undefined index: services in C:......
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'value' of non-object in C:......

Comment: elimina el `return $services;` accede con `{$service.ID}`e intenta nuevamente!

Comment: Más de lo mismo

Comment: Parece haber un objeto anidado, ¿algo así o parecido no funciona?:  `{foreach from=$services item="service"} 
   {foreach from=$service.childs item="child"} <tr>
                    <th>{$child.ID}</th> </tr>
   {/foreach} 
{/foreach}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta el `display()` de smarty

```html
$service = new Service;

$services = $service->getList();

$smarty->assign('services', $services);
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
```